# Can we map database view in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, view

I have 5 tables to use in one mvc view. So I created a database view and want to map this view  into EF for using it as a model. How can I do?

Comment: Do you use Code First?

Comment: Yes - you can access a view from EF - just like a table, really. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the following in a code-first application where I used Sql Server Functions as 'views' to run complex queries against the database to fetch data (I did not need inserts or updates).

```
List<MyClass> myClassItems =
    dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("Select * from  dbo.MyClassFunction(@param)", param).ToList();
```

I returned `myClassItems` as the result of a Repository function, with `MyClass` a class with properties that match the columns that the `MyClassFunction` returned.